# Remix Gas Limit, Transaction Cost, Execution Cost calculation

Tags: remix, evm, gas-limit, gas-estimate

As can be seen in the screenshot, I am trying to deploy an entirely empty smart contract locally. The gas limit is set to 3, so logically, this should revert the transaction, right? However, it successfully deploys the contract with the following gas, execution cost, and transaction costs. I wanted to understand why this happens. Also, how is the gas limit estimated by the compiler (in this case, 77,126), and what kind of actions account for the execution (12,666) and transaction (67,072) gas being spent on an empty smart contract creation? Thank you.[image]